# Is being would be a right replacement for is?

Tags: grammar, british-english

English is not my mother's language.  Yesterday i started to read Charles Dickens' Great Expectations and stumbled on the very first sentence.  Here it is:

> "My father's family name being Pirrip, and my Christian name Philip,
>   my infant tongue could make of both names nothing longer or more
>   explicit than Pip. So, I called myself Pip, and came to be called
>   Pip."

I wander whether it would be appropriate to replace the word "**being**" with "**is**" so it would not spoil the sentence as a whole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Being" cannot be replaced with "is" without adding a preposition that would link this clause (which is a *subordinate* clause) to the main clause (the one that begins with "my infant tongue...).

If you want to reword it, it should be something like,

> Since (*or* Given that) my father's family name **was** Pirrip, and my Christian name Philip,...

(The whole narrative is in the past, so if we transform a participle into a regular verb, it should also be in Past Simple).

Rest assured that Dickens is not known to have been a writer who was in the habit of **spoiling** the English language...

It's better not to try to reword what you read into your own understanding of what the language *should* be like, but to assume that English writers know English better than you do, and to learn from their word and tense choices. Even if we are talking about the times of Dickens, with the language *being* a bit outdated (but by no means *spoiled*) by now.